# Regex for java project

Tags: java, regex

How would I do java regex for the following examples each its taken in by scanner as a string and regex can only be set after the scanner has taken in each part so where regex can be set is after the scanner e.g

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String veriableName = scan.nextLine();
String studentID = scan.nextLine();
String word = scan.nextLine();
................
//regex can only be set here
String veriableNamePattern = "";
String studentIDPattern="";
String wordPattern="";
.............
if(veriableNamePattern.matches(veriableNamePattern ){
System.out.println(veriableName + " is valid.");
}
else{
System.out.println(studentID + " is valid.");
}
```

here are the examples I am trying to do:
A variable name composed of some alphabetic character followed by any sequence of letters or numbers.

A student ID number represented by 7 digits that must start with 1 and end with the letter s.

Any four letter word that ends in ‘ed’.

A product code represented by two digits followed by three capital letters.

Find all € values from €100 to €999 at the beginning of a line.

Comment: Please mention what regex you tried?

Comment: Why are you assuming that if variable pattern has not matched, then studentId is valid?

Answer (score 0):

Just.. read through your code, treat it like a term paper, you proofread those too, surely:

1. You are calling `veriableNamePattern.matches(veriableNamePattern)` - it won't, of course. You want to match `veriableName`.
2. You print `studentID + " is valid."` in both cases, making it impossible to tell the difference. presumably you want to introduce a `not` somewhere in that second println lline.

Answer (score 0):

Some examples:

```
// first letter optionally followed by a letter/number/underscore (\w) group
String variablePattern = "[a-zA-Z]\\w*";

// Sequence of digits starting with 1, followed by 6 digits, ending with 's' or 'S'
String studentIdPattern = "1[0-9]{6,6}s|S";

// Sequence of 2 letters followed by "ed"
String fourEdPattern = "[a-zA-Z]{2,2}ed";
```